# How do I use fetch() to populate a variable with data from the server?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

I hava a function that gets data from the Open Weather API and assigns some values to the innerText properties of some HTML elements. This part works fine.

But I also need to store one of those values (`data["main"]["temp"]`) to a property of an object (`userData.temp`).

```
//Function to get data from Open Weather
const getWeatherData = () => {
  let zipInputValue = document.getElementById("zip").value;
  const weatherUrl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${zipInputValue},${weatherCountryCode}&units=metric&appid=`;
  fetch(weatherUrl + weatherApiKey).then((res) => {
    if (res.status != 200) {
      console.log("Looks like there's been a problem.");
      return;
    }
    res.json().then((data) => {
      descriptionElement.innerText = "Weather: " + data["weather"][0]["description"];
      currenttempElement.innerText = "Temperature:" + data["main"]["temp"] + " °C";
      userData.temp = data["main"]["temp"];
      mintempElement.innerText = "Min.:" + data["main"]["temp_min"] + " °C";
      maxtempElement.innerText = "Max.:" + data["main"]["temp_max"] + " °C";
    });
  });  
  console.log(userData.temp);
};
```

In the end of my code, there is a function `generate()`, triggered by a click event, that calls `getWeatherData()` and then posts `userData.temp` to the server by calling the function `postProjectData(userData)`.

```
/*---------- Post Data to the Server ---------- */

const postProjectData = async (userData) => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/addData", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(userData),
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  const response = await rawResponse.json();
  return response;
};

/*---------- Generate Entry ---------- */

const btn = document.getElementById("generate");
btn.addEventListener("click", generate);

function generate() {
  getWeatherData();
  console.log("test");

  userData.date = newDate;
  userData.userResponse = getUserResponse();

  postProjectData(userData);

  getProjectData();
}
```

However, when this click event is first called, the property goes empty to the server. The second time, it goes with the value of the previous iteration. Meaning, it's also one iteration behind.

I'm assuming this is because when the browser gets to the `fetch` inside `getWeatherData()`, since it's an asynchronous function, it moves on to `postProjectData(userData)`; and only after that, `fetch` actually populates the property.

Am I thinking it right?
And how do I populate the property in the proper iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not waiting for the data to arrive to post it to the server. You could refactor `getWeatherData` and `generate` to make it so.

The first thing is to return a Promise from `getWeatherData` so you could wait for the data to be fetched:

```
const getWeatherData = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let zipInputValue = document.getElementById("zip").value;
  const weatherUrl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${zipInputValue},${weatherCountryCode}&units=metric&appid=`;

  fetch(weatherUrl + weatherApiKey).then((res) => {
    if (res.status != 200) {
      console.log("Looks like there's been a problem.");
      return reject();
    }
    res.json().then((data) => {
      descriptionElement.innerText = "Weather: " + data["weather"][0]["description"];
      currenttempElement.innerText = "Temperature:" + data["main"]["temp"] + " °C";
      userData.temp = data["main"]["temp"];
      mintempElement.innerText = "Min.:" + data["main"]["temp_min"] + " °C";
      maxtempElement.innerText = "Max.:" + data["main"]["temp_max"] + " °C";

      resolve();
    });
  });  
  console.log(userData.temp);
});
```

The main point here was to resolve/reject the Promise to let the function caller (in this case `generate`) that the data was fetched.

Then we refactor `generate`:

```
async function generate() {
  await getWeatherData();
  console.log("test");

  userData.date = newDate;
  userData.userResponse = getUserResponse();

  postProjectData(userData);

  getProjectData();
}
```

The idea is to convert `generate` into an async function to make it wait for the data to arrive (`getWeatherData`) in order to call `postProjectData`.